# ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: tor (missing)

Tags: tor, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I'm trying to add alpine package [tor](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/tor) and getting a following error:

```
root@linode:~/# docker run -it alpine /bin/sh
/ # apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.4.4-14-g3b19e7e [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main]
v3.4.4-12-gebd7753 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community]
OK: 5973 distinct packages available
/ # apk add tor
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  tor (missing):
    required by: world[tor]
/ # apk info tor
/ # 
/ # cat /etc/alpine-release 
3.4.3
/ # uname -a
Linux fb9225b194cb 4.7.0-x86_64-linode72 #1 SMP Thu Aug 4 15:15:18 EDT 2016 x86_64 Linux
/ #
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see at [pkgs.alpinelinux.org](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=tor&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=), tor is not in v3.4 (last stable), just in edge (unstable). It will be in the upcoming release v3.5.

Since we are just migrating from openssl to libressl in edge, I’d be very risky to mix stable and edge now. Therefore I recommend you to build tor package on v3.4 yourself.

Read [how to prepare your environment](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Creating_an_Alpine_package#Setup_your_system_and_account), clone [aports repo](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports), replace `libressl-dev` with `openssl-dev` in [community/tor/APKBUILD](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/blob/master/community/tor/APKBUILD) and run `abuild -r -i tor` (in the `community/tor` directory).